# Converting Mongodb query in java

Tags: java, mongodb

Hi my mongo collection having following documents

```
{ 
      "_id" : ObjectId("523db8f324c8fa2acac03703"), 
      "name" : "abc",
      "timestamp" : 1379776720000
}
{ 
      "_id" : ObjectId("523db8f324c8fa2acac03704"), 
      "name" : "abc",
      "timestamp" : 1379776730000
}
{ 
      "_id" : ObjectId("523db8f324c8fa2acac03705"), 
      "name" : "abc1",
      "timestamp" : 1379776800000
}
```

And I was write mongo query for finding largest timestamp of given name as below

```
db.collections_name.find({"name":"abc"}).sort({"timestamp":-1}).limit(1)
```

It work fine on mongo shell but I want to implement this query in Java code, How I write same query in Java.

Answer (score 3):

```
MongoClient mc = new MongoClient();
DB db = mc.getDB("...");
DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("...");
DBCursor c = collection.find(new BasicDBObject("name","abc")).sort(new BasicDBObject("timestamp",-1)).limit(1);
```

Don't forget to put your db and collection name